# Example 2, Sec. 16 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The subspace topology and the order topology on $[0,1)\cup\{2\} \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Here is Example 2, Sec. 16 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $Y$ be the subset $[0, 1) \cup \{ 2 \}$ of $\mathbb{R}$. In the subspace topology on $Y$ the one-point set $\{ 2 \}$ is open, because it is the intersection of the open set $\left( \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2} \right)$ with $Y$. But in the order topology on $Y$, the set $\{ 2 \}$ is not open. Any basis element for the order topology on $Y$ that contains $2$ is of the form $$ \left\{ \ x \ | \ x \in Y \ \mbox{ and } \ a < x \leq 2 \ \right\}$$ for some $a \in Y$; such a set necessarily contains points of $Y$ less than $2$.

I think I've properly understood this example.

Now my question is, can we find a set in the order topology on $Y$ that does not belong to the subspace topology that  $Y$ inherits from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

My feeling is that this is not possible.

Comment: Digression: Although the subspace topology on $Y$ is not its order topology,  the subspace $Y$ is homeomorphic to an ordered  space :Let $f(x)=x$  for  $x\in [0,1)$ and $f(2)=-2.$... On the other hand the subspace topology on $(0,1)\cup \{2\}$ cannot be generated by any linear order.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can actually write the possible forms of the open sets of $Y$ under the order topology, now try to find an open set in R that will induce the same types of open set under the subspace topology(easy to find), so ans is no!

Answer (score 0):

On a subset $S$ of an ordered space  $(T,<),$ the induced order topology is always  a subset of the subspace topology.

A sub-base $B$ for the induced order topology on  $S$ is all sets of the form $(\leftarrow,s)_S=\{u\in S:u<s\},$ or  $(s,\to)_S=\{u\in S:u>S\},$ (over all $s\in S$), or $S$ itself. Each member of $B$ is open in the subspace topology as it it the intersection of $S$ with an open set of $T$. E.g.  $(s,\to)_S=S\cap \{t\in T:t>s\}$ when $s\in S.$